# Can I apply for US student J-1 visa while staying in UK as a tourist, being a Russian national?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

My friend from Russia is planning to visit me in United Kingdom as a tourist.

But she also needs to apply for United States students visa J-1 to start her scientific collaboration in 2018 as a part of her PhD study.

Thing is: due to... ahem... astute politics of Mr. Putin, who recently limited the staff of US embassies in Russia with 400 empolyees, the queue for application at US embassy in Moscow is 1-3 months long, while in London your appointment takes 1-4 days: https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/wait-times.html/.

Question is: can she apply at US embassy in London, while staying here with me as a tourist?